# In unity, how to access EventSystem debug info in script

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

when i debug game in pc, following EventSystem is useful to debug event
[image]

but some pointer event work in pc not work in android, so I wanna get full EventSystem info in android, if I can access EventSystem info in script, I can show it in UI text, so how to access?

Answer (score 1):

I find the solution, Unity Editor has EventSystemEditor class, it has following code:

```
public override void OnPreviewGUI(Rect rect, GUIStyle background)
{
  EventSystem target = this.target as EventSystem;
  if ((Object) target == (Object) null)
    return;
  GUI.Label(rect, target.ToString(), this.previewLabelStyle);
}
```

so the EventSystem preview is `EventSystem.current.ToString`

the result is like:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can also set value using Text.

```
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class EventSystemDebug : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Text eventSystemText;

    private void Update()
    {
        if (eventSystemText)
            eventSystemText.text = EventSystem.current.ToString();
    }
}
```